# SQL calculate MTD out of YTD

Tags: sql

I try to calculate in SQL MTD cost of a table.

I have following table:

| year | user | month | type | cost | blank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | a | 1 | type1 | 10 | 0 |
| 2021 | a | 2 | type1 | 20 | 0 |
| 2021 | a | 3 | type1 | 35 | 0 |
| 2022 | a | 1 | type1 | 5 | 0 |
| 2022 | a | 2 | type1 | 35 | 0 |
| 2021 | b | 1 | type1 | 10 | 0 |
| 2021 | b | 2 | type1 | 30 | 0 |

What I need to have is now the MTD cost as per year, user and type

| year | user | month | type | cost | costMTD | blank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | a | 1 | type1 | 10 | 10 | 0 |
| 2021 | a | 2 | type1 | 20 | 10 | 0 |
| 2021 | a | 3 | type1 | 35 | 15 | 0 |
| 2022 | a | 1 | type1 | 5 | 5 | 0 |
| 2022 | a | 2 | type1 | 35 | 30 | 0 |
| 2021 | b | 1 | type1 | 10 | 10 | 0 |
| 2021 | b | 2 | type1 | 30 | 20 | 0 |

Can i do this with a query in SQL?

I tried like this but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT t1.year, t1.user, t1.month, t1.type, t1.cost, 
iif(t1.month = '1', t1.cost, t1.cost- t2.cost) AS costMTD, 0 AS blank
FROM dbo.usercosts AS t1 INNER JOIN dbo.usercosts AS t2 
ON t1.year = t2.year 
AND t1.user= t2.user 
AND t1.type= t2.type 
AND t2.month = iif(t2.month = '1', '1', t1.month - 1)
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? I've posted a standard SQL answer that should work in most RDBMS, but it's recommended (well rather demanded actually) to tag SQL requests with the MBS they are refering to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LAG` to see the previous row's cost.

```
select 
  year, user, month, type, cost, 
  cost - coalesce(lag(cost) over(partition by user order by year, month), 0) as costmtd, 
  0 as blank
from dbo.usercosts as
order by user, year, month;
```